# Scale background image to section - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've build a section for my website. Now I need a background image for that section which is fit to my section in any resolution. I've tried so many things.

But no any luck. I don't know the problem is my image resolution or css.

```
<section class="expertise-bg"></section>    

http://codepen.io/jayDilz/pen/zqeJQo
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: `background-size:cover` doesn't work?

Comment: as @Paulie_D  said http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWwqQp & eventualy position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `background-size: cover` but then the background will be cut out of the frame on different resolution aspect ratios.

```
.expertise-bg{
  background: url("http://i63.tinypic.com/jkcfhu.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you feel like the background looks bad on small resolutions, you can also set media queries to address that, and load different images (smaller, with other perspectives).